# Can you get an Excel Workbook if you have the Excel7 window handle?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com, vsto

using the native window hooking method described here I have an excel7 window handle. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anandgeorge/2010/04/10/usage-of-nativewindow-assignhandlereleasehandle-when-unmanaged-code-is-involved/

Is there a way to use [AccessibleObjectFromWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317978(v=vs.85).aspx) to get the workbook? most of AccessibleObjectFromWindow use case seems to be to get a handle to the Application itself, but thats not what I need as I already have that through my VSTO plugin.